# Why does option refuse to append to select element?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append an option to a select element from a function that is fired when a button is clicked but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? It almost seems as if the element does not exist, because even `empty()` does not work. But if I check for its existence and show an alert, it returns that the element does exist. Here's my code.

```js
function Add(ID) {
  var text = "";
  if (ID == "1") {
    text = "January";
  } else
  if (ID == "2") {
    text = "February"
  } else
  if (ID == "3") {
    text = "March";
  }
  $("#Month").append($("<option></option>").val(ID).html(text));
}
Add(1);
Add(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Month"></select>
```

Comment: Give me your HTML as well, please.

Comment: You may be comparing a string value `"1"` to a numeric value `ID`. Try removing the quotes  from the `if`comparisons: `if (ID == "1")` for example would be `if (ID == 1)`.

Comment: I just converted your code to a snippet and it seems to work fine...

Comment: Are you looking for existing value no need to add in select option?

Comment: @Nick Exactly, the code should work well. Never seen anything like this. How do I send you the code @Phong?

Comment: It's also not a problem of comparing a string value to numeric. Everything is in string.

Answer (score 2):

Your should change from `ID == "1"` to `ID == 1`. Because you are passing number instead of character or string.

```js
Add(1);
Add(3);

function Add(ID) {
        var text = "";
        if (ID == 1) {
            text = "January";
        }
        else if (ID == 2) {
            text = "February"
        }else if (ID == 3){
            text = "March";
        }
        $("#Month").append($("<option></option>").val(ID).html(text));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Month">
  <option>--Please select--</option>
</select>
```

**Refactor code**

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
Add(1);
Add(3);

Add(0);
Add(13);
function Add(ID) {
        if(ID <= 0 || ID >= 13){
          console.log("ID: " + ID + " must in range 1 - 12");
          return;
        }
        $("#Month").append($("<option></option>").val(ID).html(months[ID - 1]));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Month">
  <option>--Please select--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Array If my answer was helpful to you, you should accept it by clicking the check-mark https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help you.

```js
function Add(ID) {
  var text = "";
  if (ID == "1") {
    text = "January";
  } else
  if (ID == "2") {
    text = "February"
  } else
  if (ID == "3") {
    text = "March";
  }
  var optionExists = ($("#Month option[value=" + ID + "]").length > 0);
  if (optionExists == true) {
    console.log('Already Exist=>' + ID);
    return;
  }

  $("#Month").append($("<option></option>").val(ID).html(text));
}
Add(1);
Add(3);
Add(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="Month"></select>
```